# Plots.jl: plots inside for cycle

Tags: plot, julia, plots.jl

I am using Plots.jl with the GR backend.

For whatever, I cannot seem to be able to plot! inside a for-loop:

```
using Plots
fn(m,x) = m*x
plot([0, 10], [fn(1, 0), fn(1, 10)])
for m in 2:4
    plot!([0, 10], [fn(m, 0), fn(m, 10)])
end
```

[image: plot inside loop]

Oddly enough, the same thing without using a cycle works:

```
using Plots
fn(m,x) = m*x
plot([0, 10], [fn(1, 0), fn(1, 10)])
plot!([0, 10], [fn(2, 0), fn(2, 10)])
plot!([0, 10], [fn(3, 0), fn(3, 10)])
plot!([0, 10], [fn(4, 0), fn(4, 10)])
```

[image: plot without loop]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because the plotting itself happens when the `Plot` object is returned to the console, which implicitly calls the `Base.display` function. The `display` method on a `Plot` object generates the plot that you see. 
Objects generated within a `for` cycle aren't automatically returned to the console, which means you can't see the plot; but you can display them by explicitly calling `display`:

```
using Plots
fn(m,x) = m*x
plot([0, 10], [fn(1, 0), fn(1, 10)])
for m in 2:4
     display(plot!([0, 10], [fn(m, 0), fn(m, 10)]))
end
```

or

```
p = plot([0, 10], [fn(1, 0), fn(1, 10)])
for m in 2:4
     plot!(p, [0, 10], [fn(m, 0), fn(m, 10)])
end
p
```